# Exception in DrawerLayot component after switching to appCompat and v4 to 23.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, drawerlayout

I am working with Drawer layout and after updating my app to build version 23.0.1 ,I am facing below exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLayoutDirection(Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)I in class Landroid/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat
```

My Drawer Layout .xml file is as below

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_stub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/nav_drawer_bg_color"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@color/transparent"              
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And build .gradle for my app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.file.operator.help"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile project(':LicensePlateSannerLibrary')
    compile project(':cardflight-sdk')`enter code here`
    compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
    compile files('libs/mint-4.0.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
}
```

Thank in advance .Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem recently after upgrading the Android Support libraries to the latest version. My solution was to remove all the support library dependencies from my project and then re-add them starting with the Support Design library, and then AppCompat etc.. The design library has a dependency against the latest AppCompat, despite the other answer it is not a replacement for AppCompat.

I imagine the problem is down to a clash of the versions, or something get stuck in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the appCompat library from your dependicies , just use the support design library it is made to replace it .

Comment: @RishabhBhardwaj remove the support v4 too , only the support design should stay and try again .